# Wordpress site maigration issue

Tags: wordpress

i have a question regarding wordpress site migration. If we get a backup through wordpress dashboard using a plugin, do we neeed to get a database backup manually or it will automatically backup in the firstplace? i mean throgh the plugin we used?

I'm using All-in-oneMigration plugin

Answer (score 0):

The "All-in-One WP Migration" plugin for WordPress is designed to handle a complete site backup, including both your site's files and its database. When you create a backup using this plugin, it collects and packages all of your website's themes, plugins, uploads, and database into a single file (.wpress) that you can use to migrate your website to another server or domain.

In other words, you **don't need to manually backup your database** when you use the All-in-One WP Migration plugin. It automatically backs up your database along with your other files.

To restore your website from a backup created with this plugin:

1. Install a fresh WordPress setup on your new host or domain.
2. Install and activate the All-in-One WP Migration plugin on this new setup.
3. Use the plugin's "Import" function to upload and unpack the backup file you created.
4. Once the import is complete, your website should be restored and operational on the new host or domain.

Remember to check that everything is working properly after the migration. You may need to update some settings, like the website's URL, and some plugins might require additional configurations after the migration.

It's always a good idea to make another backup before you start tinkering with the settings on the new site.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).